# How can I do filter reading lines of .CSV file C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a file that is structured.
In the application you write has two load two files and compare the first two elements that are the same in both files.
If the same load the first element and the second element combobox1 and combobox2.
In the second combobox when you choose the respective year shall read fourth element selected year?
From the fourth to the last element of each row are the months from January to December, and the third element of each row are the days of the month from 1 to 31.
How can I read data for each month of the chosen year from combobox ?

```
18050,1976,1,0.390,0.660,0.290,0.740,9.160,1.400,0.670,3.120,0.460,0.420,0.360,0.400,
18050,1976,2,0.390,0.520,0.290,0.740,7.540,1.270,0.670,2.660,0.460,0.420,0.360,0.380,
18050,1976,3,0.390,0.450,0.240,0.660,5.260,1.270,0.670,2.510,0.460,0.420,0.410,0.400,
18050,1976,4,0.390,0.450,0.240,0.660,4.400,1.180,0.620,2.360,0.460,0.410,0.400,0.440,
18050,1976,5,0.390,0.450,0.290,0.660,4.220,1.080,0.620,2.360,0.460,0.410,0.400,4.750,
18050,1976,6,0.520,0.390,0.240,0.580,4.040,1.270,0.620,4.200,0.460,0.410,0.380,2.810,
18050,1976,7,0.390,0.390,0.240,0.520,3.680,37.800,0.620,5.870,0.460,0.400,0.360,1.620,
18050,1976,8,0.390,0.390,0.200,0.580,3.330,22.900,0.580,4.570,0.460,0.380,0.360,0.980,
18050,1976,9,0.390,0.390,0.200,0.660,2.830,11.200,0.580,4.020,0.460,0.360,0.360,0.740,
18050,1976,10,0.390,0.340,0.200,1.380,2.650,8.120,0.580,3.660,0.440,0.360,0.360,0.520,
18050,1976,11,0.340,0.390,0.200,2.260,2.350,5.870,0.580,3.270,0.440,0.360,0.360,0.460,
18050,1976,12,0.340,0.450,0.200,1.700,2.350,4.750,0.580,4.570,0.440,0.360,0.360,0.460,
18050,1976,13,0.340,0.390,0.200,1.590,2.350,3.840,0.540,4.020,0.440,0.340,0.360,0.440,
18050,1976,14,0.340,0.390,0.290,2.120,2.200,3.120,0.540,3.660,0.420,0.340,0.340,0.520,
18050,1976,15,0.290,0.390,0.290,2.400,2.050,2.970,0.540,3.270,0.420,0.400,0.340,0.520,
18050,1976,16,0.290,0.390,0.240,1.590,1.770,2.810,0.540,2.970,0.420,0.360,0.340,0.440,
18050,1976,17,0.290,0.340,0.290,1.170,1.520,2.660,0.540,2.660,0.410,0.360,0.330,0.420,
18050,1976,18,0.290,0.340,0.290,1.170,1.270,2.360,0.540,2.210,0.410,0.410,0.340,0.420,
18050,1976,19,0.240,0.340,0.390,1.170,1.080,2.210,0.540,2.060,0.410,0.410,0.400,0.410,
18050,1976,20,0.290,0.340,0.390,1.010,1.080,2.060,0.520,1.760,0.400,0.400,1.340,0.400,
18050,1976,21,0.290,0.290,0.390,0.920,1.270,1.760,0.520,1.200,0.740,0.400,2.660,0.400,
18050,1976,22,0.340,0.290,0.450,0.820,2.860,1.480,0.520,1.080,0.580,0.380,1.760,0.400,
18050,1976,23,0.340,0.290,0.520,0.740,3.050,1.200,0.520,0.980,0.580,0.380,0.980,0.400,
18050,1976,24,0.340,0.290,0.520,0.660,4.000,0.980,0.540,0.810,0.540,0.380,0.520,0.380,
18050,1976,25,0.340,0.290,0.920,0.740,2.680,0.890,2.810,0.670,0.520,0.360,0.460,0.380,
18050,1976,26,0.390,0.290,1.380,1.380,2.060,0.810,2.510,0.580,0.520,0.360,0.440,0.380,
18050,1976,27,0.740,0.290,1.490,2.570,1.770,0.810,2.510,0.580,0.490,0.360,0.420,0.380,
18050,1976,28,1.280,0.290,1.380,2.730,1.770,0.740,4.750,0.520,0.460,0.360,0.410,0.360,
18050,1976,29,1.010,0.290,1.090,3.610,1.650,0.740,5.480,0.520,0.420,0.360,0.410,0.360,
18050,1976,30,0.820,,0.820,4.000,1.520,0.670,4.210,0.490,0.420,0.360,0.400,0.360,
18050,1976,31,0.660,,0.740,,1.520,,3.660,0.460,,0.360,,0.440,
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label3.Hide();
            label4.Hide();
        }

        string pathFolder;
        string pathFolder2;

        string resultStation;
        string resultStation2;

        List<string> resultYears = new List<string>();
        List<string> resultYears2 = new List<string>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
                    pathFolder = sFileName;

                    label3.Text = pathFolder;
                    label3.Show();                 

                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);

                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        var splittedValues = line.Split(',');

                        var firstWord = splittedValues[0];
                        var firstYear = splittedValues[1];
                      // var JanuaryFirst = splittedValues[3];

                      // var lastJanuary = File.ReadLines(pathFolder).Last();
                      // var JanuaryLast = lastJanuary[3];

                        if (!resultYears.Contains(firstYear))
                        {
                            resultYears.Add(firstYear);
                        }


                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            resultStation = firstWord;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (resultStation != firstWord)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Файла с дневни данни трябва да съдържа само една станция!");
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        i++;                      
                    }
                    resultYears.Sort();
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
                    pathFolder2 = sFileName;

                    label4.Text = pathFolder2;
                    label4.Show();

                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);

                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        var splittedValues = line.Split(',');

                        var firstWord = splittedValues[0];
                        var firstYear2 = splittedValues[1];

                        if (!resultYears2.Contains(firstYear2))
                        {
                            resultYears2.Add(firstYear2);
                        }

                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            resultStation2 = firstWord;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (resultStation2 != firstWord)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Файла с месечни данни трябва съдържа само една станция!");
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        i++;
                    }

                    resultYears2.Sort();
                }
            }
        }

        public void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (resultStation != resultStation2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Номера на станцията в единия файл не отговаря на номера на станцията в другият файл!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                    "ЗАБЕЛЕЖКА!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "В двата файла, номера на станцията трябва да бъде един и същ!");
            }

            comboBox1.Items.Add(resultStation);

            if (string.Join(", ", resultYears) == string.Join(", ", resultYears2))
            //if (resultYears.Equals(resultYears2))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.resultYears.Count; i++)
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(resultYears[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Годините от двата файла не съвпадат.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably parse that data into a format that is more queryable, e.g. JSON or import to a database if you use one.

Comment: How big is your file? can it be read in one go into memory?

Comment: Yes, I Accept all options... but Can you show me .. how can I read this monster ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this problem for half an hour and I still don't know what you want to accomplish.

To get the year you would do something like this:

```
string[][] data = File.ReadLines(path).Select(r => r.Split(',')).Where(r => r[0] == station && r[1] == year).ToArray();
```

I understand that all the january numbers are in column four and if you want to read the sum you could do something like this:

```
double sum = data.Select(r => r[3]).Where(v => v != "").Sum(v => Double.Parse(v));
```

Hope this will help you on your quest.